# How to randomly generate nodes at specific positions?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I previously asked this question but deleted it and changed it since i realized I wasn't being clear.

I have five square nodes falling from the top of the screen that are all different colors. Lets say the x positions I want the nodes to fall at are 150, 250, 400 and 500. Is it possible to make it so that a red square will fall randomly from each of these positions?

This is what I have now:

```
 var MinSpawnValue: CGFloat = 300
var MaxSpawnValue: CGFloat = 700
var SpawnPosition = UInt32(MaxSpawnValue - MinSpawnValue)
first.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(arc4random(SpawnPosition),800))
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes, create a random variable in the range of 0 to 3 inclusive. If the value is 0, choose 150, if it is 1, choose 250, etc.

Comment: Can you give me an example in code please?

Comment: I think you should be able to come up with something on your own. you already correctly use `arc4random` - change the upper bound and then create if- or switch-statements. That is a task that I think you can do.

Comment: I actually have no idea what you're talking about and I learn by example which is why I'm asking for one.

Comment: I agree with luk2302, you can come up with something on your own, the problem is very easy, You take a random number from 0 to 3. If the random number is 0, your x value is 150; 1, 250; 2, 400; 3, 500.

Comment: I already figured it out. Don't need help anymore